# Convert QT Resource to ::std::istream&

Tags: qt, ifstream, qfile

I am trying to convert a QResource XML to istream. The thirdparty signature to which the XML goes into is shown below.

```
  ::std::unique_ptr< ::NO::Peoplefile >
  peoplefile (::std::istream& is,
         ::xml_schema::Flags f = 0,
         const ::xml_schema::Properties& p = ::xml_schema::Properties ());
```

But how do I convert a QResource to istream?

tried using the below, but not been able to convert it to `::std::istream&`. Any idea?

```
ifstream& QFileToifstream(QFile & file) {
    Q_ASSERT(file.isReadable());
    return ifstream(::_fdopen(file.handle(), "r")); //error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'basic_ifstream<...>' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'basic_ifstream<...>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the resource in question is XML I'm assuming it's not huge and can easily be read into memory in its entirety.  That being the case you could simply use an [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)...

```
/*
 * Attempt to open the bound resource `:/some-resource.xml'.
 */
if (QFile f(":/some-resource.xml"); f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {

  /*
   * Read its contents into an std::string which is used to
   * initialize an std::istringstream.
   */
  std::istringstream is(f.readAll().toStdString());

  /*
   * Pass the istringstream as the first parameter to peoplefile.
   */
  auto result = peoplefile(is, 0/* flags */, ::xml_schema::Properties());
}
```